# How to manage dependencies from one make file to the other when using recursive makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have an `src/` directory that contains my program sources with a Makefile to build the program.
At the root, I would like to add a Makefile to package my App.

```
AppCli.zip: src/AppCli
        # make my package

src/AppCli: # I should make it Phony or copy the dependency of AppCli in src/Makefile
        cd src/ && $(MAKE) AppCli
```

How can `src/AppCli` know its dependency directly from the makefile in the `src/` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can `src/AppCli` know its dependency directly from the makefile in
> the `src/` folder?

It can't.  You  need to delegate that info into the sub-make, so that means that your parent make *always* needs to invoke the sub-make.  It will be up to the sub-make to decide whether to rebuild or not.

However, declaring `src/AppCli` as PHONY isn't right either because it means that `AppCli.zip` will always be out of date as it depends on a PHONY target.

Instead you want to play a trick to ensure that `src/AppCli` is out of date, *but* that things depending on `src/AppCli` are out of date only if it changes.  You can do this with a "force rule", like this:

```
AppCli.zip: src/AppCli
        # make my package

src/AppCli: FORCE
        cd src/ && $(MAKE) AppCli

.PHONY: FORCE
FORCE: ;
```

Here we add a force prerequisite (it can be called anything you want, obviously) which is always out of date, which means `src/AppCli` will always be considered out of date.  However, things that depend on `src/AppCli` will only be considered out of date if the sub-make modifies it.

Comment: depend on a PHONY target makes the target always out of date but depending on a target which depends on a PHONY target makes the target out of date only if the dependency change. is it correct?

Comment: can I use FORCE with other rules or should I create FORCE1 FORCE2 if for example I want :src/AppGUI: FORCE
        cd src/ && $(MAKE) AppGUI

Comment: Yes, correct.  Basically a target that is PHONY is always "newer than anything".  But a target that is not PHONY has a normal timestamp and even if you run the recipe, if the timestamp doesn't change (the recipe doesn't update the target) then it's still not new.  It's not the case that for a normal target, if make runs the recipe it _assumes_ the target was changed.

Comment: You can use the same FORCE target however many times you want.  It just has to be "newer than anything".